# How can I recursively divide the grid in my maze?

Tags: python, recursion, maze

I am trying to create a maze generator using recursive division. I use this link:
[Maze generation - recursive division (how it works?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553775/maze-generation-recursive-division-how-it-works) as my guide as to how to approach the problem.

Here is my code so far:

```
import random
# Maze: 0 - N : 4 x 4 Grid
# Grid: 0 - (2n + 1) : 9 x 9 Array

# TODO: Now, Find a way to save the previous walls and not just only one at a time 

rows = 9
cols = 9
start = 2
end  = 7
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Lists for all even / odd numbers in given range
evens = [n for n in range(start, end+1) if n % 2 == 0]
odds = [m for m in range(start, end+1) if m % 2 != 0]
# Generate random even/odd integer value for walls/ passages respectively
# Walls: Not sure if 2 variables are necessary-----------------------------------------
wallX = random.choice(evens)
wallY = random.choice(evens)
# Passages
passageX = random.choice(odds)
passageY = random.choice(odds)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Random direction: True = Horizontal Slice, False = Vertical Slice
randomDirection = random.choice([True, False])

arr = [['0' for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)] 

def displayBoard(arr):
  print()
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
    # Print just the edges 
      if i == 0 or i == 8 or j == 0 or j == 8:
        print('*', end = ' ')
      # Print wall
      elif arr[i][j] == 1:
        print('.', end = ' ')
      else:
        print (' ', end = ' ')
    print()

# Function choose direction to slice
def chooseDir(arr):
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
      # Horizontal Direction Slice
      if randomDirection:
        arr[wallX][j] = 1
        arr[wallX][passageY] = 2
        print(arr[i][j], end = ' ')
      # Vertical Slice
      else:
        arr[i][wallY] = 1
        arr[passageX][wallY] = 2
        print(arr[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
  displayBoard(arr)

print()

mazeX = 0
mazeY = 0
# Write the recursive division function:
def divide():
  chooseDir(arr)
  print()
divide()
```

What this produces is a grid that is randomly sliced at an even index (creating walls) and creates passages at odd indices.
Output: 1 = wall, 2 = passage made

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 

* * * * * * * * * 
*       .       * 
*       .       * 
*               * 
*       .       * 
*       .       * 
*       .       * 
*       .       * 
* * * * * * * * *
```

My issue is that I don't know how to write my recursive function. Do I call division on the two new cells created when a wall is made and continuously divide the "sub cells".

Or I know that a 4 x 4 cell grid will provide an array of 9 x 9 and I will have 16 cells total.
Then I can call division until a certain condition is met, increment to the next cell until all 16 were visited.
In both cases, I am not sure how to represent the new walls/cells created so that I can write the division function. Up until now, I've been using the grid coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked "Do I call division on the two new cells created when a wall is made and continuously divide the "sub cells"". Yes, that is the essence of recursion.  Take a big problem and make smaller problem(s). Repeat with the smaller problems. Eventually, the problems are small enough to easily solve.  Then put all the small problems back together to solve the original problem.

For the maze, the first wall split the maze into two smaller mazes.  Use the same algorithm to split each of them and there are not 4 smaller mazes.  Repeat until the sub-mazes are too small to split any more.

Your code that splits the maze should go in a function. If the sub-maze is big enough to split, the function splits the sub-maze and then calls itself on the two smaller sub-mazes.